# Post Form Data using RestSharp

Tags: forms, curl, post, restsharp

I am trying to emulate the following curl command in c# using RestSharp:

curl URL -F "login=samplelogin" -F "key=password"

I am using the following c# code to format the request:

```
        // Configure Request
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
        
        request.AddParameter("login", context.Control.CourtLogin, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddParameter("Key", context.Control.CourtPassword, ParameterType.RequestBody); 

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

The client endpoint just returns login failure.  When I read the documentation for AddParameter on the RestRequest class.  It states you can only have key value pair with parameter type = RequestBody.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to get multiple form data key value pairs in a RestSharp client request?  Or how to duplicate multiple -F curl options using RestSharp?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

`"Content-Type"` should be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as the title states "Form Data" and not "x-www-form-urlencoded". Curl's "-F" is for "multipart/form-data" according to their docs: https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html#-F--form  This would be correct if the OP were passing the -d flag however.